# Offset mouse after minimizing maximized window

Tags: unity, 16.04, maximized

I recently bought a Dell XPS 13 and am running Ubuntu 16.10 with Unity. I've run into an issue where any window that is maximized, minimized, and then restored (so maximized again) causes the mouse to be offset up or down from where the pointer actually is.

This happens whether using the "Show Desktop" button, hot cornered "Show Desktop", or minimized using the window's minimize button. It doesn't happen when alt tabbing to a background application unless that application is minimized.

This seems to affect all applications (Firefox, Thunderebird,Terminal, etc) but only to the application that was minimized (meaning not all at the same time unless I minimize all the maximized windows)

To correct the issue, I have to click the maximize button again to restore the window (so not minimized and not full screen) and then maximize to maximize again. Or completely close and reopen the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the exact same bug and it was really annoying. After searching for some time I found out that I had unchecked ***show live preview of windows*** option in the switcher tab of ***compizConfig Setting Manager → Ubuntu Unity Plugin***. So the fix, for now, is to enable it back (see the screen shot below) in compiz. You can find more details about this bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1311323).

[image: Click here for my screen shot]

I hope this also works for you.

Comment: Indeed, it does solve the bug. However, if this box is checked, using a corner to hide/show all window is not possible anymore. What can we do ?

Comment: Sorry to tell you that I have not found any solution for this issue yet. People are still experiencing the same bug, even in 16.04 (just read the comments from the link below).  I use ctrl+super D keyboard shortcut to show/hide desktop for now.  You can track this bugs progress from this link https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1311323

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was facing this problem since i unchecked the "Switch between minimized windows" in "Switcher" Options of "Unity Tweak Tools". Checking it again solved the issue.

[image: Unity Tweak sceenshot]